# how can i get the fonts attributed

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

i've a single UIButton to set the text bold and unbold in UITextview

```
    let range = mainTextView.selectedRange
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: mainTextView.attributedText)
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)]
    string.addAttributes(attributes, range: mainTextView.selectedRange)
    mainTextView.attributedText = string
```

My question is how to unbold the selected text if it is already bold? how to check if the selectedRange is already bold or not?

Comment: Check the font and look for the its `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits`. Or if you only have one font, check if the font name is the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I need to remove the bold format only while unbold so how to do that?

Comment: Now I am using .attributesAtIndex() to get the attributes and result show as follows ["NSFont": <UICTFont: 0x7b79c580> font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt]

Comment: Set a new attribute for the font (bold or unbold), and it should do the trick.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Would be great if you posted it as an answer